# Get HTML without sub-children

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a piece of HTML code that looks something like this:

```
<span class="name">SOMEUSERNAME<span class="meta">20 friends</span></span>
```

With a simple `$(".name")` I can easily the insides, but is there a way to get just the username without the meta data? I know I could use RegEx, but I'd rather know if it can be done with jQuery selectors directly, since I'm still somewhat new to that thing.

Comment: you just need `$('selector').get(0).childNodes[0]`

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto that assumes that the markup will always be in that exact same format (which may actually be the case).  Just worth noting that the solution won't work for generic markup structures where only child text is desired.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like something that would be easier without jQuery

```
document.querySelectorAll('.name')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHZf3/1/)

for more elements you can do

```
var users = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.name')).map(function(el) {
    return el.firstChild.nodeValue;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHZf3/2/)

or for older browsers

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.name');
    users = [];

for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
    users.push(elems[i].firstChild.nodeValue);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHZf3/3/)

or more jQuery'ish

```
var users = $.map($('.name'), function(el) {
    return el.firstChild.nodeValue;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHZf3/5/)

Comment: Thing is, I have a few hundreds of these and wanted to create an array of the user names, not just the first one.

Comment: @user3216060 - That's not a problem, note that jQuery does not return an array either, unless you iterate, for instance with map().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var name = $('#name').clone();
name.find('.meta').remove();
console.log(name);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the most efficient approach, but this should work:

```
$('.name').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

---

Edit: here's a more efficient solution:

```
var text = $.map($('.name').contents(), function(node) {
    return node.nodeType === 3 ? node.nodeValue : '';
}).join('');
```

---

Edit: just for fun, here's a potentially "more idiomatic" jQuery approach:

```
var text = $($('.name').contents()).filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).map(function() {
    return this.nodeValue;
}).get().join('')
```

Comment: I love the chainy-ness of this.

Comment: this solution has the worse performance

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto Yes, the performance is poor... but not likely to be a bottleneck either. Updated my answer with a better solution, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you just want the username (without the 20 friends stuff)

```
$(".name").clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9GEfY/

Comment: this solution has the worse performance

Answer (score 0):

`.contents()` will return all children, including text nodes. You can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/MnCDb/

```
$(".name").contents().get(0).textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try like this?

```
 <span class="name" id="name">SOMEUSERNAME
 <span class="meta" id="meta">20 friends</span>
 </span>
 <button onClick="foo()">click me </button>

 <div id='result'></div>
 <script>

 function foo(){
 var names=document.getElementById('name').innerHtml;
 document.getElementById('result').innerHtml=names;
 }


 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span').filter(function(){return this.className=='name'}).get(0).firstChild;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Uz986/)**